# Google Address validation different result between JS and C#

Tags: c#, google-maps

If I run address validation on the address "1 Rose" from Javascript by calling this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/GeocodeService.Search?4s1%20Rose%St&7sUS&9sen-US&callback=XXX&client=XXX&token=XXX

I get 0 results. Which is what I would expect.

If I run the address validation in C# on the address "1 Rose" by calling this:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1+Rose+St&client=XXXX&sensor=false

I get a validate address "1 Rose St, North Providence, RI 02904, USA", which i totally unexpected.

Why is this happening in the c# side? and what would I need to do to get the invalid address returned in C#?

Comment: Well, you're calling two different API endpoints, so it seems likely that each API exhibits slightly different behaviour and that it's nothing to do with the language you're using. I imagine if you made the exact same call from C# as you make from Javascript you would get the same result.

Comment: Why do you expect no results? 1 Rose St is a valid address. You can query it with either the Geocoding [client-side service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) or the Geocoding [web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start). Both return the same place ID, regardless of the programming language in use. Can you please clarify what you're doing?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation